# How to set Access Permission to Cloud Formation Template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to set access permission to cloud formation template using IAM policies . If yes how to set the access policies ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to IAM and search for "cloudformation" in the Policies section you will see a read-only policy called, "AWSCloudFormationReadOnlyAccess". You can of course make you own custom policies but this is where you can restrict the use of CloudFormation.

For the actual templates you can use policies or a role to an S3 bucket that contains the policy template.

Using a combination of the two methods above you can get very granular on how CF and templates are used.